# Detecting additions to a Javascript object's properties

Tags: javascript, properties

Other than regularly polling for changes, is there any (standard) way to register an event or callback that will be triggered any time a new property is added to a specific object?

Comment: Might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169524/javascript-property-change-event

Comment: @Shadow - detecting a change to an existing property is easy, the question is about detecting addition of _new_ properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, the answer is **no**.

Mozilla's JavaScript implementation has an overload for unresolvable methods, but it doesn't work for standard properties, see [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod).  Of course, you asked for a standard method and no other implementations support this as far as I'm aware.

Comment: I rather suspected as much, but figured a decent set of answers and/or workarounds in one place would be of benefit.

Comment: @Alnitak: I went looking for an answer to the same question a long time ago.  Perhaps we'll see something like this standardized in a future revision of the specification.

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time, ActionScript supported the __resolve property. As far as I know, JS has no similar crossbrowser construct, but maybe you could simulate it with some simple (but still bloaty) accessor function, like this:

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/789987-does-javascript-support-some-kind-__resolve-method